# Admob status idle

Tags: android, admob

Suddenly my app stop showing adds, When I check admob site. It showed yellow colored triangle on it. Saying.

> Your site was previously active but has not sent an ad request in the previous 72 hours.

How to solve it please help.
Any help will be regreted.

Answer (score 0):

which sdk are u using and when did you last update your app?

Upgrade the sdk to latest or better switch to Google Play Services as the stand alone sdk will soon be deprecated.
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/

Also, if you updated recently and the problem started with that then there is some problem in your code.

Update: I just noticed it myself in legacy admob, after 3 days of me updating to new admob. Have you migrated to new admob recently?

Comment: What is the reason for this status.

Comment: I noticed it in my admob (legacy) too. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

This means that Admob has not recorded an AdRequest in the last 72 hours. You either have a very low number of users (and none have caused an aAdRequest to be sent in the last 3 days).

Or you have a fault in your app and it has stopped making ad requests. Did you update it about 3 days ago?